# Re-scaling a vector along a direction

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I have a vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that has the following decomposition:

$$ a = a_1 + a_o $$

where $a_1$ represents the component of $a$ along vector $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $a_o$ is the remainder, i.e., $a - a_1$.

I would like to remove from $a$, some component of $a$ along the direction $b$, i.e.,

$$ a - \gamma . \text{proj}_b (a) $$

for some $\gamma > 0$ using the defn of projection from rmm93's answer. However, when I set $\gamma = 1$, the results were the same as with $a$. So, I am not sure what I might be missing here.

Comment: You must have made a mistake, since $\operatorname{proj}_b(a-\operatorname{proj}_b(a))=0$ always holds. Without you elaborating on what you did and how you get your wrong results, there's nothing we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the projection of $a$ onto $b$ is as follows.

$$a_1 = \frac{b^T a}{b^T b} b$$

Hence, if you want to scale $a_1$ by $\gamma$, that would just be

$$\bar{a}_1 = \frac{1}{\gamma} \frac{b^T a}{b^T b} b$$

Comment: thank you - when I do $a - \gamma \bar{a}_1$, then, I am not able to remove all the components of $a_1$ in $a$ with $\gamma = 1$. Is there something that I may be missing? thank you

Comment: Well, when you look at $a - \gamma \bar{a}_1$ you are removing the component of $a$ that is parallel to $b$ from $a$ regardless of whether or not $\gamma$ is $1$. Hence, the remaining component is always going to be perpendicular to $b$, you can verify this by checking $(a-\gamma \bar{a}_1)^T b = 0$ given the definition of $\bar{a}_1$ from my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

From you equation $\bar a_1^T b = \frac{a_1^T b}{\gamma}$ I read that you want to set
$$
\bar a_1 = \frac{1}{\gamma} a_1.
$$
Since $a_1 = \operatorname{proj}_b(a)$ this does indeed yield
$$
\bar a_1 = \frac{1}{\gamma} \operatorname{proj}_b(a).
$$

I'm not sure if that's all you are asking for. If it isn't, please clarify in your question.

Comment: thank you - when I do $a - \gamma \bar{a}_1$, then, I am not able to remove all the components of $a_1$ in $a$ with $\gamma = 1$. Is there something that I may be missing? thank you

Comment: i updated my question above.